# Automation Error while running Geoprocessing tool using VBA in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.2, arcobjects, vba, linear-referencing

I am trying to run a geoprocessing tool in ArcGIS 10.2 as a part of a VBA GUI (kind of) that I'm trying to create - unfortunately it gives me an automation error.

I'm new to VBA and ArcGIS.

The complete Error message is: 
Run-time error '-2147467259 (800040005)'
Automation error 
Unspecified error

Here's the code:

```
' Make Route Event Layer - used to create points on the line or at an offset

Dim parameters As IVariantArray
Set parameters = New VarArray 

parameters.Add "Address"
parameters.Add "POINT"
parameters.Add "DistRRP"

Dim GP As Object
Set GP = CreateObject("esriGeoprocessing.GpDispatch.1")
GP.MakeRouteEventLayer_lr InSegmentPath, POST_NAME, tablePath, parameters, Output, "Offset"
```

The Gp.MakeRouteEventLayer line is highlighted when I Debug. Everything after GP.MakeRouteEventLayer_lr are string/names that have been declared and initialized.

I have also used another syntax which gives me the same error:

```
Dim GP As Object
Set GP = CreateObject("esriGeoprocessing.GpDispatch.1")
GP.MakeRouteEventLayer_lr InSegmentPath, POST_NAME, tablePath, "rkey POINT mile", Output, "Offset"
```

All of these refer to paths of tables or field names.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn aboout our focused Q&A format.  Why are you trying to do this in VBA instead of arcpy or something else that's still fully supported?  Is that the entire error message?

Comment: @Midavalo I'm using a version of ArcMap that has VBA. Also, I've already coded quite a bit - no reason to turn back now. Also, I'm not familiar with ArcPy.
The complete Error message is: Run-time error '-2147467259 (800040005)'
Automation error
Unspecified error

Comment: I understand you're using a version with VBA, it's still there in 10.4 too, it's just not used much anymore so might make it harder to get help.  Also I suggested arcpy as you've already stated "I'm new to VBA"

Comment: Can you explain your `parameters`?  I can't get into the 10.2 online help, but looking at more recent help I can't make sense of your parameters.

Comment: Does your other code work using `"rkey POINT mile"`?  That's how I would have presented it rather than in an array `("rkey", "POINT", "mile")` although my VBA is **very** rusty so maybe that's not how an array is passed.

Comment: @Midavalo No it gives me the same error.

Comment: @Casey could you be able to answer?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm out of suggestions - I can't get the help for pre-10.3 ArcGIS to open, so I've just been guessing.

Comment: I made the experience, ArcGIS GP Tools don't like chars like '-' or ':' in table name, check all your inputs, maybe its the cause.